# How to estimate type II error from qvalues?

Tags: false-discovery-rate, type-i-and-ii-errors

I have approximately 4000 spearman correlation coefficients rho. I used princeton web implementation of qvalue R package for control FDR=0.05 (http://qvalue.princeton.edu/).  I was created histogram of pvalues. So now, I have histogram, ~4000 $\rho$, pvalues, qvalues, $\pi_0$, ~100 selected tests ($\rho$, pvalues, qvalues) based on qvalue < 0.05 and  corresponding pvalue < $p_0$.

I thing, that $\pi_0$ give me a horizontal line in histogram for separation FP+TN and TP+FN, so if I set vertical line to $p_0$, i get four regions in histogram: TP, FP, TN, FN. But in first column (TP FP) there is much more than 0.05% of false positive (so more than i expected). Qvalues curve in histogram start from low values to $\pi_0$.

Have I compute beta from $\pi_0$ horizontal line or from qvalues curve? Or is there another way, how to compute beta? And how to intepret qvalue curve in histogram?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with web page http://www.nonlinear.com/support/progenesis/comet/faq/v2.0/pq-values.aspx and this picture:

[image: true positive, false positive, $\pi_0$ red doted line]

False negative tests (FN) are in blue part above the red-dotted $\pi_0$ line, 
Negative tests (N) are in whole blue part, so

false omission (undiscovery) rate is equal FOR= FN/N.